# Validating an XML NCName in Java

Tags: java, xml, validation

I'm getting some values from Java annotations in an annotation processor to generate metadata. Some of these values are supposed to indicate XML element or attribute names. I'd like to validate the input to find out if the provided values are actually legal NCNames according to the XML specification. Only the local name is important in this case, the namespace URI doesn't play a part here.

Is there some simple way of finding out if a string is a legal XML element or attribute name? Preferably I'd use some XML API that is readily available in Java SE. One of the reasons I'm doing this stuff in the first place is to cut back on dependencies. I'm using JDK 7 so I have access to the most up-to-date classes/methods.

So far, browsing through content handler classes and SAX/DOM stuff hasn't yielded any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didn't find anything straightforward in any of the jdk 6 APIs (don't know about jdk 7).  a quick but possibly "hackish" way to check would be to convert it to an xml doc and see if it parses:

```
String name = ...;
if(name.contains(">")) {
  return false;
}
String xmlDoc = "<" + name + "/>";
DocumentBuilder db = ...;
db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlDoc)));
```

Comment: I thought of this as well. It's a bit heavy-handed, though. Since the annotation processor has a quick "IDE" mode and a more thorough "build" mode, maybe I can just do this during the build process. It's JAXP implementation-independent, so I like the solution. Used to validate user-provided XPath expressions via JDOM like this. Thanks for a good suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I'm gonna go with this solution. It's compact enough not to be too invasive. I was hoping one of the XML APIs would expose some interface method for validating names, but lacking that this is probably the least round-about way. As long as it prohibits faulty builds it'll serve its purpose. After all, the annotations are for our own development team and I'm assuming they're not gonna try to break the metadata with wacky names.

Answer (score 3):

If you're prepared to have Saxon on your class path you can do

new Name10Checker().isValidNCName(s);

I can't see anything simpler in the public JDK interface.

Comment: While Saxon looks like an excellent XSLT processor (just today lamented how little XSLT 2.0 support there is all around), I'd rather keep to whatever the user decides upon and use the JAXP factories. I'm guessing that for the annotation processor this wouldn't matter too much. I'll have a look at the license details, maybe find out if I can just incorporate those classes I need. Thanks! Btw, the entry on Muenchian grouping in your book was of great help to a colleague today. I'd give an extra point if I could :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and found lots of implementations in foss libraries, and even an old implementation in a Java class library, which has been removed ages ago... So here's a few options to choose from:

- Java Class Library: [XMLUtils.isValidNCName(String ncName)](http://nick-lab.gs.washington.edu/java/jdk1.5b/api/javax/xml/XMLUtils.html#isValidNCName%28java.lang.String%29) (note: [removed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4991514) in 2004)
- Apache Axis: [NCName.isValid(String stValue)](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/types/NCName.html#isValid%28java.lang.String%29)
- Saxonica: [NameChecker.isValidNCName(CharSequence ncName)](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/om/NameChecker.html#isValidNCName%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- OWL API: [XMLUtils.isNCName(java.lang.CharSequence s)](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/io/XMLUtils.html#isNCName%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- Validator.nu HTML Parser: [NCName.isNCName(java.lang.String str)](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/apidocs/nu/validator/htmlparser/impl/NCName.html#isNCName%28java.lang.String%29)

So, if you're using one of these libraries anyway, you're fine.

As I am not, I'll go with a copy of the XMLUtils from the OWL API, which has no external dependencies, is available under non-restrictive licenses (LGPL and Apache 2.0) and consists of nice and clean code.